# How to exclude button from my selection?

Tags: jquery

I have a selection like this:

```
newElement.find(':input')
```

the result is:

```
[input#id_sales_items_formset-0-id 1, 
select#id_sales_items_formset-0-sales_item, 
button.btn]
```

How can I exclude the `button.btn` please?

Comment: Note that [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) selector is deprecated.

Comment: @undefined thanks. What should I be using instead please?

Comment: You can select the `input` elements by using the tag selector, `newElement.find('input')`

Comment: like this? `newElement.find('input[type!=button]')`

Comment: Yes, this uses an `attribute selector` too, _select input tags that their type attributes are not `button`_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.not`.

```
newElement.find(':input').not('button.btn')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
newElement.find(':input').not('button.btn')
```